# Glimpse.Log4Net multi layer

Tags: model-view-controller, logging, log4net, glimpse, multi-layer

i don't know how i can get log4net logs into glimpse in others projects of my solution.
Ex:
Solution
   Project1 (Business)
   Project2 (DAL)
   project...
   ProjectWeb (glimpse & glimpse.log4net are installed here)

only logs in project 3 are catched by glimpse, when i write logs in project 1 & 2 or more glimpse is still opened but logs aren't catch by glimpse.

Is there any solutions ? I tried a lot to configure the web.config but no way to catch logs from other projects where glimpse & glimpse.log4net aren't installed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a new version of glimps log4net on nugget:

```
Glimpse for log4net 1.1.0 (this version)   283  Sunday, February 7, 2016
```

Are you using log4net 1.2.11 [2.0.0]? It seems Glimpse.Log4Net is build against that version.

Next you can enable log4net internal debugging, this show any internal exceptions:

There are 2 different ways to enable internal debugging in log4net. These are listed below. The preferred method is to specify the log4net.Internal.Debug option in the application's config file.

• Internal debugging can also be enabled by setting a value in the application's configuration file (not the log4net configuration file, unless the log4net config data is embedded in the application's config file). The log4net.Internal.Debug application setting must be set to the value true. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This setting is read immediately on startup an will cause all internal debugging messages to be emitted.

• To enable log4net's internal debug programmatically you need to set the log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging property to true. Obviously the sooner this is set the more debug will be produced.

Internal debugging messages are written to the console and to the System.Diagnostics.Trace system. If the application does not have a console the messages logged there will be lost. Note that an application can redirect the console stream by setting the System.Console.Out. The Trace system will by default send the message to an attached debugger (where the messages will appear in the output window). If the process does not have a debugger attached then the messages are sent to the system debugger. A utility like DebugView from http://www.sysinternals.com may be used to capture these messages.

As log4net internal debug messages are written to the System.Diagnostics.Trace system it is possible to redirect those messages to a local file. You can define a trace listener by adding the following to your application's .config file:

```
<configuration>
    ...

    <system.diagnostics>
        <trace autoflush="true">
            <listeners>
                <add 
                    name="textWriterTraceListener" 
                    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                    initializeData="C:\tmp\log4net.txt" />
            </listeners>
        </trace>
    </system.diagnostics>

    ...
</configuration>
```

Make sure that the process running your application has permission to write to this file.

[log4net FAQ](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)